# How to disable sound when receiving notification from FCM in expo react-native-app

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I am sending notifications from dotnet server using Firebase admin to React Native app. Everything is working fine in every situation (foreground, background, dead) but I want the user to be able to disable sounds from notifications when app is in background or dead. I have tried to not include the sound option in dotnet server but I am still hearing the sound. This is the code on my server:

```
    var messaging = FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance;
    var message = new Message()
    {
        Notification = new Notification
        {
            Title = notificationToBeSent.Title??string.Empty,
            Body = notificationToBeSent.Message ?? string.Empty
        },
        Data = notificationToBeSent.Data,
        Token = notificationToBeSent.RecipientId// "TARGET_DEVICE_TOKEN" // Replace with 
    };
    var result = await messaging.SendAsync(message);
```

In my React Native application I have used messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging and I have noticed that the notification module is been deprecated so every solution that included that option is no more valid. The code in my React Native application for handling background notifications is this.

```
     messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
         console.log("......",remoteMessage.notification?.android?.sound)
         console.log('Message handled in the background!', 
          remoteMessage.notification?.android?.sound);});
```

sound is undefined but i am still hearing the default notification of my device.

Answer (score 0):

there is a solution

```
const notify = {
     ...message.notification,
     show_in_foreground: true,
     notify_type: message.NotificationType,
     obj_id: message.ObjectId,
     sound: '' // remove this
};
firebase.messaging().createLocalNotification(notify);
```

Comment: Thank you Gennady for the answer but i have issues implementing it. I guess this is something that i should do inside the setBackgroundMessageHandler. My main problem is that the messaging module doesnt have a createlocalnotification method.

Comment: then try to send like `sound: ''` on back-end side.
maybe it will be helpful)